# Icon to represent smooth?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I am looking for icon ideas on how to represent a smoothing quality. The icon will be used for a tool that will smooth out points on a jagged curve.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! What have others used previously to show something becoming smooth? In other words, please do your own research and work and then come back here with questions for further refinement of your concepts. Please see our [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how GDSE works and how to ask and answer questions appropriately inline with our community standards.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest an icon that literally demonstrates the process you're trying to show:

Take a jagged circle, and turn it into a smooth one.

[image]

Similarly, take a jagged line and make it curvy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've also seen an iron used for this kind of functionality